# Adding css backgrounds that span the entire width of the page to content with a div that has boostrap's container class on it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a website using bootstrap where the div wrapped around all of my main content has a class of container on it. This is so my site does not stretch the entire page and is centered with a fixed width. However throughout certain parts of my main content I would like to have backgrounds that do span the entire width of the page.

Essentially what I am trying to do is something like this attempting to give the content in div with the id rowWith100PercentBG a background that spans the entire screen:

```
<div id="mainWrapper" class="container">
    <div id="rowWith100PercentBG" class="row container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a jsFiddle of what I have:
https://jsfiddle.net/jyh359mh/

The part that is missing is that I need an orange background behind Section 1 that spans the entire width of the sceen and a red background behind Section 2 that spans the entire width of the screen. By spans the entire width of the screen I mean covering the black on the sides, but still behind the content in the sections. Each section will need its own bg.

Comment: Provide us an example

Comment: @JinuKurian Don't go removing `container`s. That's not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Put the container fluid outside and the row inside

```
<div id="mainWrapper" class="container-fluid">
<div id="rowWith100PercentBG" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
    #mainWrapper{
    background-color:black;
    height: 200px;
}

#rowWith100PercentBG{
    height: 100px;
    background-color:Green;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/johnny5er/npexfp7L/)

Comment: I'm not sure if this fully answers my question. I need all of my primary page content in some sort of container just like bootstraps 'container' class takes care of where it centers the content on the screen. But I need to put 100% width fluid backgrounds behind all of the content. Adding a css background to the body is not a solution it needs to be the backgrounds of divs with class row on my page.

Comment: @Johnn4er please see the bottom of my post for a clear explanation of what I am looking for and a jsFiddle example. Sorry I didn't post this in the first place.